# How many levels are there in Affordable Space Adventures?

Tags: affordable-space-adventures

How many levels are there in Affordable Space Adventures?

I've reached level 16 but the map doesn't let me scroll to see how many levels there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed the main difficulty. There are **39** levels in it.

The "Tourist" difficulty might be different but the first few levels seem to be the same.